# Apt-Get using Apt-Cacher NG fails to fetch packages with hash sum mismatch

Tags: networking, apt, apt-cacher-ng

I have a machine who is using Apt-Cacher NG running on another machine as caching proxy.

When I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/it.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty.

To fix that I have already tried the following with no success:

Solution 1:

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Solution 2:

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have seen this behaviour sometimes. Running **sudo apt-get update** several times consecutively helped in this case but I don't know why, never investigated this issue more closely.

Comment: This happens also on machines which don't use Apt-Cacher NG. In those cases Solution 1 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest to switch away from APT-cacher-ng and check out Squid-deb-proxy.

APT-cacher-ng has proven to be *very* buggy in my experience and tons of bug reports are outstanding. Only recently it has been [proposed](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=694378) again to get unblocked in Debian now that some major bugs are squashed. For Ubuntu I've switched to Squid-deb-proxy a long time ago and I don't regret it. It's a great alternative and the best APT-cacher I've come around.

For Squid-deb-proxy, just install the package [`squid-deb-proxy`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/squid-deb-proxy) and add allowed destination domains in a new file in `/etc/squid-deb-proxy/mirror-dstdomain.acl.d`. As a bonus, clients can auto-discover caching-enabled machines in the local network by having the [`squid-deb-proxy-client`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/squid-deb-proxy-client) package installed.

Answer (score 10):

You can fix this right now by running:

```
http://your-cache-server:3142/acng-report.html?abortOnErrors=aOe&byPath=bP&byChecksum=bS&truncNow=tN&incomAsDamaged=iad&purgeNow=pN&doExpire=Start+Scan+and%2For+Expiration&calcSize=cs&asNeeded=an#bottom
```

This will delete all the broken files in your cache.

To make this permananet, have a look at https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/maint.html#auto-cleanup

Basically, you can set up the daily cache cleanup cron to do a full checksum match on your entire cache. This will catch all the bad sizes and any other corruption and clean out those files. I edited `/etc/cron.daily/apt-cacher-ng` and added the following after the comments:

```
export ACNGREQ="abortOnErrors=aOe&byPath=bP&byChecksum=bS&truncNow=tN&incomAsDamaged=iad&purgeNow=pN&doExpire=Start+Scan+and%2For+Expiration&calcSize=cs&asNeeded=an"
```

This is equivalent to clicking all the expiry options on the maintenance page except "Skip header checks..."

Comment: This was the only answer that got rid of the error on my systems!

Comment: I think you may need a `?` at the start of your export string.

Answer (score 3):

### Suggestion 1

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*gzip*
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*gzip*
sudo apt-get update
```

### Suggestion 2

```
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/partial/*
sudo rm -f /var/cache/apt/*.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

### Suggestion 3

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache
```

And paste this in:

```
Acquire::http {No-Cache=True;};
```

Now try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks but none of the three worked.

Comment: Worked like a charm setting no-cache to true! Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have been fighting VERY frequently (1 in 50 downloads) with "Hash Sum Mismatch" and "Invalid Header" errors using `apt-cacher-ng` on Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS since the day of upgrading the distro. Ubuntu Precise uses `apt-cacher-ng` version 0.7.2-1, to date there are MANY bug fixes to this software, and the newer version: 0.7.26-1 is much more stable.

I have installed the Ubuntu Quantal version of `apt-cacher-ng` from packages.ubuntu.com, which is version 0.7.26-1.

I highly recommend grabbing the future/testing version of `apt-cacher-ng`, and manually installing this newer package.

Answer (score 1):

My upgrades would always *almost* succeed -- 95% of the files would download through the proxy, leaving maybe the last ~100 files failing with 'hash sum mismatch', and none of the proposed solutions would ever work.

And then, just for grins-and-giggles, I moved `01proxy` over to `01proxy.ng`, ran `aptitude update`, then `update-manager` and selected the distribution-upgrade.  It proceeded to download the remaining files from archive.ubuntu.com (~70M rather than ~1G), and the rest of the upgrade went smoothly.  After rebooting, I moved 01proxy.ng back to 01proxy, and everything was back to normal.

I've done this twice now, once on the proxy server itself and once on a client, and both succeeded just beautifully after failing (at that 95% mark) when going through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/download.virtualbox.org` folder did help me to fix the problem with `Failed to fetch ... Hash Sum mismatch` on `apt-get update` that prevented `virtualbox-4.3` package from Oracle server.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 4**

Running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` on the Apt-Cacher NG server may fix the problem. You need to do that every time the problem occurs.

**Suggestion 5**

Sometimes the problem is on the mirror: changing the mirror in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, both on the server and the clients, may fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the whole repository folder

```
rm -r /var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/<repository_folder>
```

where the package with the hash sum mismatch is stored.

On next apt request a new folder with clean hash sum will by automaticaly created by apt-cacher-ng.